# Convert a tupple into integer Python, error message: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a list of tupples, which I want to converto to a list of integers.
My function get_ids returns a list of tupples like so: [(8720581,), (8755416,),...]

```
def send_to_MQ():
    
        
     credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(rabbit_username, 
     rabbit_password)
  connection=pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(rabbit_server, 
     rabbit_port,"/", credentials ))
     channel = connection.channel()
    
     channel.queue_declare(queue=rabbit_queue, durable=True)
     mapped_ids=get_mapped_ids()
     for mapped_id in mapped_ids:
         mapped_id=int(mapped_id)
         
         channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hhh', body=mapped_id)
     print("Mapped ids sent to RabbitMQ")
```

When I ran the code above, I got: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, tuple found and I tried the following solutions:

```
for mapped_id in mapped_ids:
         mapped_id=int(mapped_id[0])
```

but I have this error: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

and

```
for mapped_id in mapped_ids:
             mapped_id=int(mapped_id)
```

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'tuple'

Comment: Could you create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? At the moment, we don't have enough details to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second and third sample are identical. Both should have worked fine, though. Yet another way to accomplish this could be

```
mapped_ids = get_ids()
for mapped_id, in mapped_ids:
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hhhh', body=int(mapped_id))
```

However, please check if `channel.basic_publish` actually expects an integer as its `body=` argument; I would have expected it wants a string.

Comment: Thank you .You are correct, it was expecting a string. I changed the code to: for mapped_id, in mapped_ids:
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hhhh', body=str(mapped_id)) .